# Unable to subscribe to ics based calendars in Mountain Lion

Tags: icalendar

I have an iCalendar ics based calendar that I publish on my website. Works great in Outlook (Windows), iCal (SL, Lion) and GMail. I'm just unable to subscribe to this in Calendar 6.0 in ML though.

To verify that it's not just me that is crazy, I downloaded a working ics from Apple (webcal://ical.mac.com/ical/US32Holidays.ics) which WORKS in ML and uploaded it to my site at webcal://www.gbnetworksinc.com/US32Holidays.ics and it throws the same error.

"There was an unspecified error with the request on subscribed calendars (error -1)"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I see that RememberTheMilk is publishing events to ML Calendar just fine. Any idea on what I'm missing? Probably some header or something, from the looks of it.

Answer (score 2):

Maky,
I ran into the same problem.

if you are running a IIS server, you have to change the MIME type of the .ics to text/calendar , that should do the trick!